# How do I 'exec' a bash command like this where an option is multi-word?

Tags: bash, escaping, exec, quotes, double-quotes

On the commandline I can run my binary this way:

```
theBinary_exe -q 'more than one word' -f foo -b bar
```

When I put that in a bash script and run the script it's all fine. But if I do this in the script:

```
CMD="theBinary_exe -q 'more than one word' -f foo -b bar"
exec $CMD
```

The 'q' argument only passes the first word to the executable. I tried using \" as well with no luck. Is there a wrapping I can use to prevent that when I use exec?

Comment: What if you put the `'more than one word'` in a variable ?

Comment: @Pierre I get the same error if I replace the above with -q $VAR and set VAR='more than one word'

Comment: Quote your variables, unless you know exactly when to leave then unquoted.

Comment: Hey @tripleee, do we have a canonical question for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Do not use a regular parameter](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Use an array:

```
args=( -q 'more than one word' -f foo -b bar)
theBinary_exe "${args[@]}"
```

Comment: ... or use positional parameters, `set -- -q 'more than one word' -f foo -b bar; theBinary_exe "$@"`

Comment: The positional parameters aren't always available to be used like that.

Comment: The OP (and the title) indicate using `exec` to invoke the program, which means there's no use for the positional parameters after `exec`, and `set --` is Posix (unlike arrays).  However, I see you (and I) invoked the program *without* exec, so it's a valid argument in that case that one might still need the original positional parameters after the program returns (or if `exec` fails).

Comment: If they really need `exec`. It's not clear from the question that they understand what `exec` does, and they are just using it because they think that's how you execute a a command in a script.

Comment: I agree and upvoted your comment. I found a way, using functions, to avoid clobbering the positional parameters when invoking the program, and will post that as a separate answer just for grins.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments it is not clear that `exec` is necessary in this case. `exec` (if successful) will replace `bash` with `theBinary_exe`, the invoking `bash` is gone... anything following the `exec` in the bash script is ignored, there's no longer an interpreter to read it when `theBinary_exe` terminates.

`theBinary_exe` can be invoked directly, `bash` follows prescribed rules when executing commands: splitting into words, looking for redirections and variable assignments, and looking for a command name after expansions.

The command name could be `theBinary_exe`, instead of `exec`.  If the command name matches a function name, that takes precedence, if a function 'shadows' `theBinary_exe` you can override that by using `command theBinary_exe` and tell bash you mean the binary, not the function.

If you know there's no shadow function

```
theBinary_exe -q 'more than one word' -f foo -b bar
```

If there is a function by that name or if you just want to make sure no function is invoked

```
command theBinary_exe -q 'more than one word' -f foo -b bar
```

Sometimes you need to 'build' the parameters conditionally, in that case the solution by @chepner of using an array is the idiomatic way to construct the list of arguments and then expand them into positional parameters at invocation.  Arrays are widely supported, but not POSIX.

If portability is a concern consider using a function.  One advantage of functions is that the caller's positional parameters (and the special $#) are preserved, see [Shell-Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Functions) in the reference manual.  By using an intermediary function you can solve the problem

```
function run_theBinary_exe {
   set --
   if $condition_1; then
      set -- -q 'more than one word'
   fi
   if $condition_2; then
      set -- "@" -f foo
   fi
   if $condition_3; then
      set -- "@" -b bar
   fi
     
   command theBinary_exe "$@"
}
```